# in my API view i want to upload video in background using serializer , i want to return response and i dont want to wait until video upload complete

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my ApiView and i am uplaoding video to GCP bucket using serializer and video is filefield i am new to djngo DRF so can you please help me. how can use threading my case?

```
class TestsApi(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
        if request.method == "POST":
            if request.data.get('video') is not None:
                serializervideo = VideoSerializer(data=request.data)
                if(serializervideo.is_valid()):
                    serializervideo.save()
                "Rest of the code"
                return Response(result)
```

i want to upload video completely in background, i dont want to wait until video uploaded to my bucket i want to return response.

Thank you in advance.